# No headphone or speakers plugged in - Windows 7 issue

Tags: windows-7, laptop, audio, sony-vaio

I am facing a wierd issue between my sound card driver and Windows7(any edition). I have a sony vaio notebook (VPCEB24EN). Two days ago, on start I got diabled wifi, charging and speakers. Then I restart the PC and everthing worked fine. Later on I again restarted my machine, and then I found the my speakers were not working. I thought, restart will work. I restarted many more times but it did'nt work. I searched google and found that , it might be due to :
1. Hardware is not switched on from bios.
2. No hardware.
3. overriding 64-bit drivers with 32-bit drivers.

To make it working, I restored my laptop from scratched, but while restoring pc, the realtek HD drivers, it gave me an error 505. I then formatted the drive and installed Win7 Ultimate 32bit (With PC was, Win7 64-bit Home Basic). I got lots of yellow exclamation in device manager, thinking now this will resolve my issue. But Even after the installing all drivers on a fresh installation, I was still with the same position.

`A red cross on speaker- No Speakers or Headphone plugged in.`

Please Note:

1. [My Laptop is Vaio , E Series, VPCEB24EN.](http://www.sony-asia.com/product/vpceb24en)
2. Audio : Intel® High Definition Audio compatible but accepts Realted Audio. While using BIOS Agent, I got Intel Chipset 5 Series Audio Adapter and ATI RV370 Audio adapter found on my board.
3. Installed is Win7 32bit Ultimate. factory default was Win7 64-bit Home Basic
4. Memory: RAM 3GB/ 320GB HDD
5. Display : ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 5145 Graphics

Comment: I have the same problem and not sure if it's a hardware(audio board) or cable issue. Does your faulty FFC cable allow a USB or external USB sound to work when plugged in?

Comment: I am not sure about the USB Audio, but my USB pendrives were working fine. When the show me the FFC cable,i noticed that few fine metallic lines were damaged..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to install the updates from [Sony](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/VPCEB24EN)

Comment: I did that too, My hardware is detected and it accepts only Windows Generic Driver. Any other driver or codec from realtek is not accepted.

Comment: and the realtek? did you try to the one from official page?
http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/

Comment: try to load defaults in BIOS...

Comment: another source to drivers http://drp.su/drivers/notebooks/?v=Sony&m=VPCEB24EN&id=22550&l=en

Comment: tried all ways to update driver.... Finally dropped to Sony Service Center and found that the Audio FFC Cable was faulty....